Re use for 2 steps in GitHub action job - same ID
I created a GitHub workflow that is reusable (using the on.workflow_call) with 1 job. It accepts input called app-name. This job is set with these 3 steps:
            - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
              id: build-image
              env:
                  ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
                  ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ env.RESOURCES_NAME }}
                  IMAGE_TAG: ${{ steps.package-version.outputs.current-version }}-${{ github.sha }}
                  DOCKERFILE_PATH: ./docker/Dockerfile.${{ inputs.app-name }}-cloud
                  PHONES_DATABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.PHONES_DATABASE_URL }}
              run: |
                  docker build --build-arg PHONES_DATABASE_URL=$PHONES_DATABASE_URL -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG -f $DOCKERFILE_PATH .
                  docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
                  echo "image=$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

            - name: Download task definition
              run: aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition $RESOURCES_NAME --query taskDefinition > $TASK_DEFINITION_FILE_NAME

            - name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition
              id: task-definition
              uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1
              with:
                  task-definition: ${{ env.TASK_DEFINITION_FILE_NAME }}
                  container-name: ${{ env.RESOURCES_NAME }}
                  image: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.image }}

The problem is, that I only need to provide this PHONES_DATABASE_URL env (in the first step under env field), and only use it under 1 condition: only if ${{ inputs.app-name }} == "MY_VALUE".
So basically this workflow should be with these 4 steps:

            - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
              id: build-image
              if: ${{ inputs.app-name }} == "MY_VALUE"
              env:
                  ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
                  ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ env.RESOURCES_NAME }}
                  IMAGE_TAG: ${{ steps.package-version.outputs.current-version }}-${{ github.sha }}
                  DOCKERFILE_PATH: ./docker/Dockerfile.${{ inputs.app-name }}-cloud
                  PHONES_DATABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.PHONES_DATABASE_URL }}
              run: |
                  docker build --build-arg PHONES_DATABASE_URL=$PHONES_DATABASE_URL -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG -f $DOCKERFILE_PATH .
                  docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
                  echo "image=$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

            - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
              id: build-image
              if: ${{ inputs.app-name }} != "MY_VALUE"
              env:
                  ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
                  ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ env.RESOURCES_NAME }}
                  IMAGE_TAG: ${{ steps.package-version.outputs.current-version }}-${{ github.sha }}
                  DOCKERFILE_PATH: ./docker/Dockerfile.${{ inputs.app-name }}-cloud
              run: |
                  docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG -f $DOCKERFILE_PATH .
                  docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
                  echo "image=$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

            - name: Download task definition
              run: aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition $RESOURCES_NAME --query taskDefinition > $TASK_DEFINITION_FILE_NAME

            - name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition
              id: task-definition
              uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1
              with:
                  task-definition: ${{ env.TASK_DEFINITION_FILE_NAME }}
                  container-name: ${{ env.RESOURCES_NAME }}
                  image: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.image }}


But of course, I get an error for duplicate id of steps: id: build-image.
So what would be the solution for such a case?

First:
If those are never running in the same sequence, why use the same name?
But anyhow, you can do:
      - name: Set optional build args
        if: ${{ inputs.app-name }} == 'MY_VALUE'
        id: set-optional-build-args
        env:
            PHONES_DATABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.PHONES_DATABASE_URL }}
        shell: bash
        run: |
            export BUILD_ARGS="--build-arg PHONES_DATABASE_URL=${PHONES_DATABASE_URL}"
            echo "BUILD_ARGS=$BUILD_ARGS" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR (MY_VALUE)
        id: build-image
        env:
          ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
          ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ env.RESOURCES_NAME }}
          IMAGE_TAG: ${{ steps.package-version.outputs.current-version }}-${{ github.sha }}
          DOCKERFILE_PATH: ./docker/Dockerfile.${{ inputs.app-name }}-cloud
        run: |
          docker build ${{ env.BUILD_ARGS }} -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG -f $DOCKERFILE_PATH .
          docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
          echo "image=$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT


      - name: Download task definition
        run: aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition $RESOURCES_NAME --query taskDefinition > $TASK_DEFINITION_FILE_NAME

      - name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition
        id: task-definition
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1
        with:
          task-definition: ${{ env.TASK_DEFINITION_FILE_NAME }}
          container-name: ${{ env.RESOURCES_NAME }}
          image: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.image }}

The BUILD_ARGS will empty if the condition is false, so the command will look as you want in both cases.
Note that I didn't run the code, so some adjustment may be needed.
In general, utilizing bash commands can make life much easier with gh action, the API is still missing a lot options.
